# jQuery on scroll not working with createElement on JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which creates a div via `createElement()` in JavaScript.
The problem is that the `scroll` event is not fired on this div. The weird thing is that the click event fires but not the scroll event. This worked well when I created the div via `$.html()` on jQuery.

Also my two other functions that scroll the div on hovering on `.direction_left` and `. direction_right` don't work either. Also these worked well when I created the div via `$.html()`. What is the problem here? Thanks.

this is the `scroll function to load data via ajax`.

```
var scroll = true;

$(document).on('scroll', '#infinited', function() {
    alert('scroll');
    var div = $(this);

    if(div[0].scrollWidth - div.scrollLeft() == div.width()) {

        if(scroll == true) {
            $.post('ajax/user/get_infinited.php', {'start': div.children().length}, function(data) {
                if(data == '')
                scroll = false;
            div.append(data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

this is the function which creates the `infinited` div.

```
create_infinited: function() {
    if(!document.getElementById("i")) {
        var i = document.createElement("div");
            i.id = 'i';
            i.style.position = 'relative';

        var infinited = document.createElement("div");
            infinited.id = 'infinited';

        var direction_left = document.createElement("div");
            direction_left.className = 'direction_left';

        var direction_right = document.createElement("div");
            direction_right.className = 'direction_right';

        i.appendChild(direction_left);
        i.appendChild(infinited);
        i.appendChild(direction_right);

        $('#search_form').after(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you write everything natively or everything using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because the `scroll` event doesn't bubble up in the DOM (if you check for example the `click` event, it will work and that proves that the problem is not in your code - or at least not the way you'd expect).

However, in modern browsers you can capture the scroll event on the document level via the `addEventListener`, like this:

```
document.addEventListener(
    'scroll', 
    function(event){
        var $elm = $(event.target);
        if( $elm.is('#infinited')){
            // put your code here
        }
    },
    true
);
```

Or you can move your "data loader logic" to a function (let's call it `getInfinited`) that can be accessed in `create_infinited`, and subscribe there:

```
$('#search_form').after(i);
$('#infinited').on('scroll', getInfinited);
```

Comment: Thanks works cool. What about my `hover` events, should I do the same thing with hover also?